# Dropdown menu, add more id

Tags: javascript, html

I copied this menu:

```
http://50.112.96.159/wordpress/html/facebook_dropdown.html
```

It works fine, but i have question.

I want to have more than one menu, like:

```
<dl style="" class="dropdown">
                   <dt><a id="linkglobal" style="cursor:pointer;"></a></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul id="ulglobal">
                            <li><a href="#">Everyone</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Only Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Customize</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </dd>
                </dl>

<dl style="" class="dropdown">
                   <dt><a id="linkglobal" style="cursor:pointer;"></a></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul id="ulglobal">
                            <li><a href="#">Everyone</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Only Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Customize</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </dd>
                </dl>
```

When i set #id to `<dt>`, menu doesnt work, i think its because of javascript.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: what did you mean by When i set #id to <dt>, menu doesnt work,

Answer (score 0):

The example URL you provided contains A and UL elements with unique IDs, but yours are the same for both menus. Browsers will allow duplicate IDs within a document, but it should be avoided for a few reasons - but one of which is that JavaScript will work as expected (with multiple IDs, which element is returned by getElementById() is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so if you are trying to set up two different images - I assume you are talking about privacyOff & privacyOn images you need to change your html as others suggested by firstly having unique ids, and then change your css to give the image you want to those ids, so something like:

html:

```
`<dt><a id="linkglobal" style="cursor:pointer;"></a>  ...</dt>`
```

becomes

```
`<dt><a id="linkglobalOne" style="cursor:pointer;"></a>  ...</dt>`
```

And css:

```
.dropdown dt a {background:#EEEEEE url(/wordpress/images/privacyOff.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
display:block; width:40px; height:22px; cursor:pointer;}
```

becomes:

```
#linkglobalOne {background:#EEEEEE url(<IMAGE YOU WANT>.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
display:block; width:40px; height:22px; cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: I figured out that when i remove "link" from #id, menu wont work.